# Bounded variation on [0,1] implies there is another function on [0,1] that differentiability and absolutely continuous

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

**Problem** : Let $f:[0,1]\to \Bbb R$ is of bounded variation. Prove that there exists $g:[0,1]\to \Bbb R$ which absolutely continuous and  $g'(x)=f'(x)$ for almost every $x \in [0,1]$.

I have tried to introduce $f$ as a difference of 2 monotonic functions but I'm getting stuck. I will be very happy is someone can help me with that question

Comment: This is just a restatement of Lebesgue Decomposition Theorem.

Comment: Can you explain more to me?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Prove that $f'$ is Lebesgue integrable, and then consider its indefinite (Lebesgue) integral. For the former, your approach is useful.